# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image] [image] [image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The original question mentions there will be "elections in several weeks" to elect moderators.  That was mid-December 2010.  It's been more than a few weeks since then.  Will there will be elections any time soon?

Comment: The elections will occur about 30 days after the site graduates. IT Security is still in public beta so we will retain the pro tem moderators until we can hold an official election.

Comment: @Robert, @D.W. - getting closer: we managed some excellent traction from the last couple of security conferences and have bumped attendance and Q&As. Keeping on with the awareness to colleagues, contacts, the Twitterverse etc should get us there soon.

Comment: Is there a T-Shirt or something I might wear to sport my IT Security Stack Exchange pride?  And if not, would it be frowned upon to create one?