# Official Security Stack Exchange Anniversary Competition

Tags: discussion, competition

As Security Stack Exchange has just passed its 1st anniversary of graduation, we are going to follow in the tradition of other sites and run a competition.

**With prizes! Cool ones!**

Obviously in order to deserve these prizes you'll need to put in some effort, but I know you will rise to the challenge. So without further ado, here are the details:

**Beginning on Monday the 13th of August**, for the following 4 weeks, we have selected a topic for each week. The tags for this topic will be posted below this question, and announced in chat before each Monday.

**Level 1 prizes - [Security Stack Exchange T-shirts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeMMQ.png)** - these lovely numbers are a hit anywhere (assuming you are at an IT, Security or Geek conference) - designed by @Jin and lovingly crafted in soft but hard-wearing cotton!

- One level 1 prize will be awarded for the most suggested edits that are accepted each week. (Unfortunately, this means 2k+ users aren't eligible for this method of entry.)
- Throughout the 4 weeks we will also monitor users who receive a [Revival badge](https://security.stackexchange.com/badges/59/revival), and a Level 1 prize will be awarded for the person with the highest score from answers on those questions.
- All entrants with a question or answer with a score of at least 5 will be entered into a draw at the end of the month. Each raffle winner (one question, one answer) will receive a Level 1 prize.

**Level 2 prizes - [Corsair Flash Survivor USB drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-ky0OwYZnk)** - for all your '[on a boat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487/154443)' needs. I have tested one of these in a river, and it performs as stated - it survived!

- One level 2 prize will be awarded each week to an individual whose posting activity (questions or answers) in any of the weekly topic tags (see the answer below for the topic tags) passes the following thresholds: 10 posts with a score of 1 or more, 5 posts with a score of 5 or more, 1 post with a score of 8 or more. The winners will be drawn at random from all those who pass these thresholds. Posts are cumulative so you need 10 posts total, of which 5 have a score >5 and 1 has a score >8.

**The top prize - a [WiFi Pineapple](http://blogs.computerworld.com/19671/sneak_pineapple_peak_hak5_creates_even_more_lethal_wi_fi_hot_spot_honeypot_hacking_tool)** - if you know what one of these is, you want one. If you don't, then google until you also desire one :-)

- For the top prize over the 4 weeks, the winner will need to reach even higher thresholds - 35 posts with a score of 1 or more, 15 posts with a score of 5 or more, 3 posts with a score of 8 or more. The winner will be drawn at random from all those who pass these thresholds. As with the Level 2 prize, posts are cumulative.

To give the greatest number of people a chance to win a prize, if you win a level 1 prize and then later you win a level 2 prize we will assume (unless told otherwise) that you would prefer the level 2 prize and will then assign that level 1 prize to the next highest competitor. Same goes for the level 3 prize, so although we will announce winners each week, the final result may change slightly. **To account for this, we'll track weekly winners along with runners-up for each week.**

### Additional notes:

- In order to avoid confusion days will work in UTC (as per Stack Exchange standard) and not [Canonical DMZ TimeZone](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/882/485). :-)
- Deleted/closed questions are ineligible for the event. Answers to questions that, once answered, are closed/deleted are *also* disqualified.
- For the Level 2 prize: if the tag is removed during the window of the promotion, the post is disqualified.
- Winning a weekly prize *does not* knock you out of the running for cumulative prizes. However, winning a higher-level prize makes you ineligible for lower-threshold prizes. We'll keep track of runners-up for each week to account for this.
- The event will run from **13 August** until **9 September**. Keep an eye on this meta post!
- Revival Badge is awarded for: Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

**We are in our second day of the competition - some good questions in there already, but we can always do with more. And remember to keep on suggesting good edits.**

Comment: So e.g. to get in the weekly drawing for level 2, you could post 3 questions properly tagged with one of the tags of the week, each of which gets 5 upvotes, and one great answer on some properly tagged question for 8, one good answer for 5, and 5 other answers for one apiece.  Right?

Comment: Right. The aim is to get quantity **and** quality

Comment: Does it mean that there will be prize for suggested edits per each week?

Comment: @Andrey - yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final List of Winners

**Level One**

- [image: Andrey]
- [image: Zuly]
- [image: Hope]
- [image: queso]
- [image: tylerl]
- [image: rorya]
- [image: jao]

**Level Two**

- [image: stupidone]
- [image: dgarcia]
- [image: dw]
- [image: lucas]

**Level Three**

- [image: polynomial]

All winners were chosen randomly from a pool of users who passed certain thresholds.

Congratulations to our winners! You will be contacted shortly with information on how to collect your prize.

Answer (score 7):

Activity on questions tagged with these tags, and answers on these questions will be measured during these weeks.

The Topic for week one - 13 August to 19 August:

**The often-overlooked people-related side of security**

[social-engineering](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-engineering), [people-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people-management), [physical](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) and [user-education](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-education)

---

The Topic for week two - 20 August to 26 August:

**Native code**

[shellcode](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shellcode), [dep](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dep), [aslr](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aslr), [buffer-overflow](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer-overflow), [safeseh](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safeseh)

---

The Topic for week three - 27 August to 2 September:

**Wireless**

[wifi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi), [gsm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsm), [rfid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rfid), [bluetooth](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth), [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless)

---

The Topic for week four - 3 September to 9 September:

**Smartphones and mobile devices**

[mobile](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile), [ios](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [android](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android), [windows-phone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone), [tablets](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tablets)

Comment: We should make sure all of those tags have ***good*** tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts.

Answer (score 2):

### Week One Winners:

**Top Suggested Editors**

- [image: Andrey Botalov]
- [image: HackToHell]
- [image: Luc]

**Level Two:**
No one was eligible for this prize this week. :(

Answer (score 2):

### Week Two Winners:

**Top Suggested Editors**

- [image: Zuly Gonzalez]
- [image: vignesh]
- [image: Mike]

**Level Two:** No one was eligible for this prize this week.

Answer (score 2):

### Week Three Winners:

**Top Suggested Editors**

- [image: HopeIHelped]
- [image: Alex]
- [image: MadHatter]

**Level Two:** No one was eligible for this prize this week. We are currently reviewing this and will announce winners at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

### Week Four Winners:

**Top Suggested Editors**

- [image: queso]
- [image: Brendan Long]
- [image: CodesinChaos]

**Level Two:** Only one user was eligible. Congratulations to Lucas Kauffman!

[image: Lucas]