# Praise the day! Our ursine overlord has brought more glory than ever!

Tags: discussion, bears

[Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin), [our ursine overlord](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/i-hereby-declare-the-22nd-of-september-each-year-to-be-bear-day) has reached the milestone of 200,000 reputation on Sec.SE!

Before we delve into the bear's amazing here are some *facts* about his account(s):

- The bears [are the only users to ever get the Legendary badge on Sec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary)
- [The bears together have more reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) than the following *six* Sec.SE users (i.e. [D.W.](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/971/d-w), [Polynomial](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5400/polynomial), [tylerl](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/2264/tylerl), [RoryAlsop](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/485/rory-alsop), [LucasKauffman](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/3339/lucas-kauffman) and [AviD](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/33/avid)).
- [The big bear](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) is the user with the most Gold Badges on Sec.SE
- [The](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) [bears](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5411/tom-leek) have given nearly 3,700 answers to Sec.SE
- The bears have 777 "nice answer", 160 "good answer" and 27 "great answer" badges

The list of all new answers since he got to 100,000 reputation is too long to fit a single post here, so I'll pick some of the more important ones:

- [The big bear gave the answer to the question why Google still uses SHA-1 but everybody else has to phase it out.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91446/why-is-google-still-using-a-sha1-certificate-on-its-own-site-when-they-are-phasi/91450#91450)
- [The big bear enlightened us what Logjam is and what do about it.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/what-is-logjam-and-how-do-i-prevent-it/89702#89702)
- [He enlightened the casual internet user that the NSA already is a CA and that it's actually not so fancy to be one as a spy agency.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71171/is-there-anything-preventing-the-nsa-from-becoming-a-root-ca/71174#71174)
- [It was the big bear to explain the POODLE to the average Sec.SE user, although the answer lacks a picture of a bear eating a poodle.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability/70724#70724)
- [Our ursine overlord was it to detail what to do in case quantum computers can break standard crypto - besides panic.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48022/what-kinds-of-encryption-are-not-breakable-via-quantum-computers/48027#48027)

Comment: Congrats on a great milestone.

Comment: And he's never asked any questions ?

Comment: @Criggie, not a single one on Sec.SE.

Comment: Maybe we should change the lion at the center of the Information Security graphic to a bear...