# Congratulations to our third 100k member of Sec.SE (first human member...)

Tags: discussion, reputation

Congratulations to [Steffen Ullrich](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37315/steffen-ullrich) who has just passed 100k! Like the [Great and Little Bears](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2118/485) before him, this is no small feat!

With over 2000 answers, one with 431 upvotes, and four with over 100 upvotes (almost 5) he has delivered incredible value.

- [Why is SQLi still around?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/128413/485)
- [Should I be worried about tracking domains on a banking website?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/166341/485)
- [Why do I hear about so many java insecurities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/57655/485)
- [Reasons for displaying 2 websites on single domain?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176441/485)
- [What is the relationship between SHA-2 and SHA-256?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/87156/485)

Well done for hitting 100k, Steffen!

Comment: Congratulations! (Ironically, I've never seen him on meta so hopefully he reads this. :-))

Comment: I cheekily sent him the link... :-)

Comment: @Arminius He's too busy working on catching The Bears for meta, lol.

Comment: Congratulations! Steffen Ullrich and he never asked a question on Sec.SE!

Comment: @NH. The Bear disapproves of your narrow view of intelligence.