# The bear facts!

Tags: discussion, bears

As many of you may have noticed, [our ursine overlord](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1413), Thomas Pornin, has bypassed [200k rep as the big bear](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) and [100k rep as the little bear](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5411/tom-leek).

To celebrate these glorious times where the bears rule Sec.SE we want to come together and collect facts about the bear(s).

**So please answer with amazing facts about our ursine overlord(s)!**

---

This question was inspired by [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134) and by [Schneier Facts](http://www.schneierfacts.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Praise the day! Our ursine overlord has brought more glory than ever!](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/praise-the-day-our-ursine-overlord-has-brought-more-glory-than-ever)

Comment: Ain't that a dupe?

Comment: @DeerHunter, no. The praising question is there to list the amazing (true) things our overlord has done for us. This question is here to ask for amazing "*facts*" about our overlord like in the referenced fact sites. Or do you think *"Jon Skeet's addition operator doesn't commute; it teleports to where he needs it to be."* is true?